# Replacement for redux hook inside a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I really need to have a global state inside the below function but I'm getting this error:
`Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component`

Is there a workaround or other solution for this?

```
import useVoiceHook from '../../hooks/voicehook';

const Sound = require('react-native-sound');

function PlaySound(name) {
  const voicehook = useVoiceHook();
  const voice = new Sound(name, Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, async (error) => {
    if (error) {
      console.warn('failed to load the sound', error);
      return;
    }
    if (voicehook.data.lastVoice) {
      voicehook.data.lastVoice.stop();
    }
    voicehook.setVoice(voice);
    voice.play();
  });
}
export default PlaySound;
```

Comment: How are you using PlaySound?

Comment: inside other functions or like onPress={() => PlaySound('click')}. @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: I would look into the implementation of voiceHook to see what magic sauce is going on inside. I can't imagine why playing a sound needs to be a hook in the first place.

Comment: @Martin because I need to stop other voices while playing a new one

Comment: @Martin also as the title says I'm looking for a replacement.

Comment: @MinaFa Here is what I would do: go into the voiceHook code, move all voiceHandling into a global VoiceManagement thingy, (see if the voiceHook becomes completely obsolete in the process), and call the global VoiceManagement from wherever I need it. And as I said, voiceHook probably doesn't need to be a hook.

Answer (score 1):

Since you try to use the PlaySound function on an event it throws you the error because you can't use a hook within it. Hooks are meant to be used as top level functions within a functional component.

Check the **[Rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)** for more details

You should pass the voicehook value as argument to playSound function and consume the same

```
function MyComponent(props) {
   const voicehook = useVoiceHook();
   ...
  
   return (
       <TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor: "red", padding: 20}} onPress={()=> {
             PlaySound('click', voicehook)
         }
        }>
         <Text>X</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
   )
}


function PlaySound(name, voicehook) {
  const voice = new Sound(name, Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, async (error) => {
    if (error) {
      console.warn('failed to load the sound', error);
      return;
    }
    if (voicehook.data.lastVoice) {
      voicehook.data.lastVoice.stop();
    }
    voicehook.setVoice(voice);
    voice.play();
  });
}
export default PlaySound;
```

Comment: If I could I would have used a component instead PlayVoice function in the first place :(

Comment: You only need to update your implementation to how I showed in the example. Use the useVoice hook within the component where you have onPress event handler defined and pass on the voiceHook value as param